# Update a document (quickly) - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Consider this MongoDB document:

```
      {
                "_id" : "RMa.103",
                "official_name" : "Real Madrid Club de Fùtbol",
                "country" : "Spain",
                "started_by" : {
                        "day" : 6,
                        "month" : 3,
                        "year" : 1902
                },
                "stadium" : {
                        "name" : "Santiago Bernabeu",
                        "capacity" : 85454
                },
                "palmarès" : {
                        "La Liga" : 32,
                        "Copa del Rey" : 19,
                        "Supercopa de Espana" : 9,
                        "UEFA Champions League" : 10,
                        "UEFA Europa League" : 2,
                        "UEFA Super Cup" : 2,
                        "FIFA Club World cup" : 4
                },
                "uniform" : "white"
}
```

I forgot to insert an important information of the team: **the common name**.
So, I updated the document:

```
[1] db.team.update({_id:"RMa.103"}, {$set:{common_name:"Real Madrid"}})
```

In this way, the new information is added at the end of the document, instead I want it after the official_name:

```
{
                    "_id" : "RMa.103",
                    "official_name" : "Real Madrid Club de Fùtbol",
                    "common_name" : "Real Madrid"
                                 .......
                                 .......
                                 .......
}
```

Now, I know that updating the document with the following method, I have the common name of the team in the right location:

```
db.team.update(
     {_id:"RMa.103"}, {$set:{ "_id" : "RMa.103", 
     "official_name": "Real Madrid Club de Fùtbol", 
     common_name:"Real Madrid", "country" : "Spain", 
     "started_by" : { "day" : 6, "month" : 3, "year" : 1902 }, 
     "stadium" : { "name" : "Santiago Bernabeu", "capacity" : 85454 },   
     "palmarès" : { "La Liga" : 32, "Copa del Rey" : 19, "Supercopa de Espana" : 9, 
     "UEFA Champions League" : 10, "UEFA Europa League" : 2, "UEFA Super Cup" : 2, 
     "FIFA Club World cup" : 4 }, "uniform" : "white", "common_name" : "Real Madrid" }})
```

I have to update a lot of documents and this kind of operation is very difficult and boring from the shell of the prompt. Are there faster methods to do this update? For example is it possible to change the update method of the [1]?

Comment: Is there any problem if it is at the end of the document?

Comment: No, but it's not lovely to see. And details count.

Comment: Well I am afraid can't do that.

Comment: What a bad news. Okay, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not really. You should not have to have it in a specific order. When querying from a application, it won't care what order your values are in. For example:

```
db.collection("team").find({offical_name:"Real Madrid Club de Fùtbol"},function(err,results)
{
 /*Gets the first result (should only be one)
 and prints the common name*/
 console.log(results[0].common_name); 
});
```

If you are wondering why they would not have a way to order it for human eyes, you must remember that databases are not designed to be interacted with directly. They are supposed to be in conjunction with an application that uses them and presents the data in a human friendly manner.

I hope I answered your question sufficiently, if not please comment below and I will explain more.

Comment: Very good answer. You are right: databases are in conjunction with an application. Unfortunately I have to talk about my Mongo database using the Shell (University project). Okay, this will be the reason why I have that information at the end of the document :)

Answer (score 4):

From the [JSON documentation](http://www.json.org/) :

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

So there is absolutely no way to enforce any kind of key order in JSON therefore it's the same for MongoDB documents.

It's useless : any MongoDB driver will give you the corresponding value with a given key. The key order is pointless.